# I wanna call array elements with DOM in JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have two HTML files and One JS file so I send information in first HTML pages to an array in JS and I wanna get this array in second HTML file. so I want to create element inside the Element in the second page, but when I select one of the element in the second HTML page and it gave me this error

```
(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of 
null HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>)
```

Its my code but I have link in my array and (pic1 & pic2 & pic3 & pic4) I didn't put the images links in this question

```
const infoBTN = document.getElementsByClassName('infoBTN');
const images = document.querySelector('#img');

const arr = [{name: 'Hello' , Work: 'Front End Developer' , date : '3/2/2020'} , {name: 'HI' , Work: 'Back End Developer' , date : '3/2/2020'} , {name: 'Jack' , Work: 'Full Stack Developer' , date : '3/2/2020'}];
for (let i = 0; i < infoBTN.length; i++) {
  infoBTN[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    images.innerHTML = `
    <img src=${arr.pic1} alt="${arr.name}" class="pic1">
    <img src=${arr.pic2} alt="${arr.name}" class="pic2">
    <img src=${arr.pic3} alt="${arr.name}" class="pic3">
    <img src=${arr.pic4} alt="${arr.name}" class="pic4">
   `
  })
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="images" id="img"></div>
```

Please Help Me

Comment: In the Html file, where you placed the script tag?

Comment: inside the head tag.. 
but i added defer keyword to the script tag

Comment: So there are two html files and you're trying to have an action on one page be accessible to the other? Is there a hard page refresh involved here?

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to send the array back and forth, put the array in a json